# Nodemailer and Amazon SES

Tags: javascript, amazon-ses, nodemailer

My structure:

```
site
-- node_modules
---- nodemailer
-- webclient
---- js
------- controller.js

site/node_modules/nodemailer
site/webclient/js/controller.js
```

**site/webclient/js/controller.js:**

```
    var nodemailer = require('../../node_modules/nodemailer');

    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport('SES', {
        AWSAccessKeyID: 'xxx', // real one in code
        AWSSecretKey: 'xxx', // real one in code
        ServiceUrl: 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
    });

    var message = {
        from: 'example@mail.com', // verified in Amazon AWS SES
        to: 'example@mail.com', // verified in Amazon AWS SES
        subject: 'testing',
        text: 'hello',
        html: '<p><b>hello</b></p>' +
              'test'
    };

    transport.sendMail(message, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + response.message);
        }
    });
```

This code is part of a controller where all other functions within it work perfectly.

- Is there something I am missing?
- Perhaps I'm calling for the incorrect nodemailer module?
- Or should the transport be SMTP, not SES?

I'm stuck.

Comment: You might consider describing what the actual problem is. Do you get error messages, etc.

Comment: The actual problem is it does not send an email. No error messages. Where should I be seeing it? The console doesn't return anything.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing in the right arguments to the `transport.sendMail()` function? You only pass in one function, but typically you pass in a function to handle success and a separate function to handle errors. Granted, I'm not familiar w/nodemailer, that seems a little funky for it not to have a callback for the success path.

Comment: please mark as correct answer below

Answer (score 20):

Please use aws-sdk directly. It work for me. Hope it will help you.`

```
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// configure AWS SDK
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: << SES_ACCESS_KEY >>,
  secretAccessKey: << SES_SECRET_KEY >>,
  region: << SES_REGION >>,
});

// create Nodemailer SES transporter
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
SES: new AWS.SES({
  apiVersion: '2010-12-01'
})
});

// send some mail
transporter.sendMail({
  from: 'sender@example.com',
  to: 'recipient@example.com',
  subject: 'Message',
  text: 'I hope this message gets sent!'
}, (err, info) => {
  console.log(info.envelope);
  console.log(info.messageId);
});
```

Comment: I dont understand this answer. aws-sdk do I have to install it as seperated package or this nodemiler built in? what about AWS.config what they are exactly? what is apiVersion from where I can get it? I have only SMTP credintials

Answer (score 15):

The below code is what I used and it worked for me. This is for the current NodeMailer. Where the transport module needs to be included separately. In the previous versions the transport modules were built in.

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sesTransport = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');

var SESCREDENTIALS = {
  accessKeyId: "accesskey",
  secretAccessKey: "secretkey"
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
  accessKeyId: SESCREDENTIALS.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: SESCREDENTIALS.secretAccessKey,
  rateLimit: 5
}));

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'FromName <registeredMail@xxx.com>',
  to: 'registeredMail@xyz.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Amazon SES Template TesT', // Subject line
  html: < p > Mail message < /p> / / html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info);
  }
});
```

#### UPDATE

The nodemailer library has been updated since I last wrote this answer. The correct way to use the library with AWS SES is provided in their docs. The link for a [working example](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/#example-1)

#### Further Reading

- [Nodemailer v1.0 release (ARCHIVE)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140720004045/http://www.andrisreinman.com/nodemailer-v1-0/)

Answer (score 9):

I use this code in a controller and it worked for me very well. It is using the SMTP auth from AWS SES.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config();

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'example@email.com',
  to: 'other@email.com',
  text: 'This is some text',
  html: '<b>This is some HTML</b>',
};

// Send e-mail using SMTP
mailOptions.subject = 'Nodemailer SMTP transporter';
var smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  port: 465,
  host: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    pass: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  debug: true
});

smtpTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(error.responseCode).send(error.response);
  } else {
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    res.status(200).send(info);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can see the full example in this repository https://github.com/gustavdz/nodemailer-AWS-ses-smtp

Comment: Can you explain how exactly this code dump solves OP's problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance this code uses the SMTP way to send the emails using the AWS credentials, is another way to send the emails creating a SMTP transporter and sending this way.

Comment: Thanks, works for me.
Short note: "secure: true" on prod, does not work on localhost.

Answer (score 3):

Following nodemailer transport configuration worked for me. This doesn't require AWS SDK.

```
const nodeMailerTransporter = require('nodemailer').createTransport({
    host: '<aws.smpt.host>',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: '<aws_smtp_user>',
        pass: '<aws_smtp_pass>'
    }
});
```

Where to obtain configurations:

`<aws.smpt.host>` can be found in **Server Name** value of SMTP Settings page of AWS SES console.

`<aws_smtp_user>` and `<aws_smtp_pass>` are obtained by creating SMTP credentials with **Create My SMTP Credentials** button in SMTP Settings page of AWS SES console.

Answer (score 0):

With new firebase v9 i used following code and it worked:

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: ['recipient@example.com'], // Add recipient email addresses
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: 'Hello, this is the email content!', // Add your email content here
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: 'Firebase Cloud Function Email', // Add your email subject here
      },
    },
    Source: 'sender@example.com', // Add the sender email address
  };

  try {
    await ses.sendEmail(params).promise();
    res.status(200).send('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error sending email');
  }
});
```

[Full tutorial here](https://lonare.medium.com/how-to-send-emails-with-firebase-function-and-aws-ses-service-8f90b2fec72b)

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
import * as aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses'

const ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'eu-central-1' })

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: { ses, aws }
})
```

---

---

**More detailed breakdown and explanation of the code above:**

1. **Importing Required Modules:**

```js
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import * as aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
```

This part of the code imports the necessary modules. `nodemailer` is the main module used for sending emails in Node.js applications. `@aws-sdk/client-ses` is the AWS SDK for JavaScript v3, specifically the SES client. It's a modular version of the AWS SDK, which allows you to only import the specific client you need, in this case, SES for email services.

2. **Configuring AWS SES Client:**

```js
const ses = new aws.SES({ region: 'eu-central-1' });
```

Here, an instance of the SES client is created and configured with the region where you intend to use the SES service. The region `'eu-central-1'` refers to the Frankfurt region, but you should replace this with the region that best suits your application's requirements or where your AWS resources are located.

3. **Creating a Nodemailer Transporter with AWS SES:**

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: { ses, aws }
});
```

In this step, a Nodemailer transporter object is created. This transporter is configured to use AWS SES for sending emails. The `SES` option within the `createTransport` method is specifically designed for this purpose. By passing the SES client instance (`ses`) and the AWS SDK (`aws`), you're instructing Nodemailer to send emails through AWS SES.

**Additional Explanations and Documentation:**

- **Nodemailer** is a module that allows Node.js applications to easily send emails. It supports various transport options, including SMTP, SES, and more. The official Nodemailer documentation provides a comprehensive guide on its usage: [Nodemailer Documentation](https://nodemailer.com/about/).
- **AWS SES (Simple Email Service)** is a cloud-based email sending service designed to help digital marketers and application developers send marketing, notification, and transactional emails. It's a reliable and cost-effective service for businesses of all sizes. The AWS SDK for JavaScript documentation covers how to use the SES client, among other AWS services: [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ses/index.html).

When integrating these services into your application, it's important to ensure that your AWS account and SES service are properly set up and that you have the necessary permissions to send emails. This setup might involve verifying email addresses or domains with SES and ensuring your account is out of the SES sandbox environment, allowing you to send emails to any address, not just verified ones.

Additionally, managing the security of your AWS credentials is crucial. Ensure they are not hardcoded in your application code. Instead, use environment variables or the AWS Secrets Manager to keep them secure.

Comment: while answering somebody, please add more descriptive explanations since the one looking for an answer would get what you're talking about. In some cases if you should add a link to a documentation and describe shortly what the doc says, or if you are putting code snippets as the answer please write some comments for your code.

Comment: Please add some description so people can understand what the code is when they read in the future

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

export default async function mail({ toAdress, subject, text, html = null }) {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    // Credentials for user with SES access in AWS.
    SES: new aws.SES({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    }),
  });
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'your@email.com',
      to: toAdress,
      subject: subject,
      html: html,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.error(error.response.body);
    }
  }
}
```