# How to send out SES email from a Lambda NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

Can someone give me a working example code? I use NodeJS v6.14.4
Below is my pseudo code.

I am new to NodeJS. If someone can provide a working sample code to at least send out SES email from a node JS as a reusable user function then that would be great.

I am looking to structure my NodeJS code like this manner:
--------------index.js-----------------------------
initialize aws library.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

    // Read the invoking SQS queue.
    var queueType = getQueueType(SQL_URL);

    // Send customer welcome email for Reseller Type ='RS'  
    if(queueType == 'RS') {
       SendSESEmailRS(params);
    }

    // Send customer welcome email for Reseller Type ='EY'  
    if(queueType == 'EY') {
       SendSESEmailEY(params);
    }


}

function SendSESEmailRS(params){
   // code to send out SES Email
}

function SendSESEmailEY(params){
   // code to send out SES Email
}    

// Get the Reseller type from the invoking queue.
function getQueueType(params){
   // code to retrieve the Reseller shortForm from the SQS queue which is invoking this Lambda Function.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I made a simple solution for you. Go here
https://github.com/mdhelaluddin-ctg-bd/ses-email-nodejs

Download these code from Github. Install and configure by reading the readme.md instruction. It's easy.

create another file for lambda function. put the 'require' (npm packages) parts to the header and remaining part inside the **exports.handler = function(event, context) { }** function. Then create a zip of this project folder and upload as in lambda function as as zip...

Then DONE !!!

> Feel free to ask at comment if you face any further problems. Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  Could you kindly give the code for this part "put the 'require' (npm packages) parts to the header and remaining part inside the exports.handler = function(event, context) { } function" . Sorry I am totally new to NodeJS, and just signed up for an online course to learn Node. Some of the terms I am still trying to understand.  I have installed your ses-email bundle from Git.

Comment: I meant this part
--
require('dotenv').config()

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ses = new AWS.SES();
--

Comment: @jcoder let me know if you understand or not what I meant

Comment: No I did not use your library. I managed to implement the whole solution just by using NPM nodemailer and NodeJS AWS SDK

Answer (score 0):

I like to use **nodemailer** library to deal with different kind of emailing.
Few links for you with examples:

- https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/
- [Nodemailer and Amazon SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982299/nodemailer-and-amazon-ses)